# Use of Async / Await to write to SQL using three Tasks

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await

I have a program that reads from 7 different PLC's at generally the same time using background threads. Using the 7 different reads, I am hoping to write to three different SQL tables.

```
public static async void readReady()
{
    if (Read1_complete && Read2_complete && BCS_complete == true)
    {
       await Task.Run(() => W1_SQL_Write.SQL_Write_Enabled());
    }
    if (Read3_complete && Read4_complete && BCS_complete == true)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => W2_SQL_Write.SQL_Write_Enabled());
    }
    if (Read5_complete && Read6_complete && BCS_complete == true)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => W3_SQL_Write.SQL_Write_Enabled());
    }
}
```

The 7 read methods call this `readReady()` method, and if the other reads flags are set, one of the three SQL write tasks gets started.

I am new to async and await tasks. I am wondering if this is a good way to go about calling different methods to write to SQL?  Will the second and third "if" statements wait for the first to return, when the first "if" statement is called true before hand?

It is possible that all three write methods come true at the same time, so will this cause some bugs too, or is async and await the way to go about doing it?

Comment: Don't use `async void`, it should only be used for event handlers.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to explicitly compare to true (BCS_complete == true).

Comment: I am not sure how else to go about it without checking the conditions of the individual flags that signify the reads have been completed.  Would you help me to post some different ideas?

Comment: The BCS_complete is the 7th PLC that is being read, I guess I should have explained it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible that all three write methods come true at the same time, so will this cause some bugs too, or is async and await the way to go about doing it?

When you read `async` and `await` code, try to think of it like this... for every `await` statement the code that follows will not execute until the "awaited" operation completes and returns, or errors out. This is true for both `Task` and `Task<T>` (as well as other awaitables, i.e.; `IAsyncOperation<T>`, `IAsyncAction`, etc).

> I am wondering if this is a good way to go about calling different methods to write to SQL?

I'm not sure I fully understand this questions specifically. Nine times out of ten, I prefer using the asynchronous programming paradigm for `I/O bound` operations -- database interaction is most certainly `I/O bound`, so yes.

> Will the second and third "if" statements wait for the first to return, when the first "if" statement is called true before hand?

The `if` statements themselves are not waiting for anything. They will execute as quickly as possible, but because of the `await` keyword they will not be executed until the async operation is finished. So one can read this code and expect a "serialized" execution where the order of the code reads just like synchronous code. Does that make sense?

I would probably rewrite this as follows:

**Update:**

```
public static async Task ReadReadyAsync()
{
    if (!BCS_complete) return;

    if (Read1_complete && Read2_complete)
        await Task.Run(() => W1_SQL_Write.SQL_Write_Enabled());

    if (Read3_complete && Read4_complete)
        await Task.Run(() => W2_SQL_Write.SQL_Write_Enabled());

    if (Read5_complete && Read6_complete)
        await Task.Run(() => W3_SQL_Write.SQL_Write_Enabled());
}
```

You had a check before every call to see if the `BCS_complete` bit was set. So I added an early exit. Then since all of these calls will execute in a serialized manner we can write them that way.

Comment: That does make sense, This post does answer my questions very well.  Your code above leaves out that the three reads that call the `readReady()` need to all be true before the write gets called, but your description of async and await is explained very well.

Comment: I updated my code example. I'm not sure what else you need me to update, but I'd be happy to add clarity if needed?